# How to push a class to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a component TextAreaField that has some default classes. I am wondering how can I push or add a new class to that component.

```
     <TextAreaField
          name="summary"
          label={{ id: 'Form.Summary' }}
          maxLength={200}
          rows={1}
          readOnly={readOnly}
        />
```

If I just add property `className` like this:

```
      <TextAreaField
          name="summary"
          label={{ id: 'Form.Summary' }}
          maxLength={200}
          rows={1}
          readOnly={readOnly}
          className="new-class"
        />
```

Then I overwrite the existing default classes, and I would only like to add a new one to it, how can I do that?

Comment: What is TextAreaField? Is it from a library?

Comment: That depends on `TextAreaField` implementation, btw how about `className="new-class old-class(es)"` .

Comment: do you mean css class

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain the classes in an array like this:

```
let classes = ["class1", "class2"...];
```

Then you can add/remove class from using standard array methods like push/pop. Maintaining them as an array makes it easier to manage classes conditionally.

You can pass the final classes to your component by joining all the classes by a space like this:

```
<TextAreaField
          name="summary"
          label={{ id: 'Form.Summary' }}
          maxLength={200}
          rows={1}
          readOnly={readOnly}
          className={classes.join(" ")}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `className` use another property-name like `classNames` or `classes` and add that to the default classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) library, which handles the class joining:

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';

export default TextAreaField = ({ className }) => (
  <Textarea className={ classnames('myDefaultClassName', className) } />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use CSS modules in reactjs provided
Follow this step
https://medium.com/nulogy/how-to-use-css-modules-with-create-react-app-9e44bec2b5c2